# ¿Como quitar los null de una consulta?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

espero puedan ayudarme, quisiera sustituir los null por cero en una consulta, este es mi codigo.

```
create view Vista
as
select Caja.CodigoEmpacador as CODIGOEMP,Caja.NumPresentacion as PRESENTACION,Empacador.Nombre as NOMBRE,
Empacador.ApellidoP as APELLIDO_PATERNO,Empacador.ApellidoM as APELLIDO_MATERNO,
 Fecha as FECHA,ISNULL(NULLIF(sum(Cantidad), 0) , '')as CajasXPresentacion
 from Empacador inner join 
(Caja inner join Presentacion on Caja.NumPresentacion =Presentacion.NumPresentacion )on 
Empacador.CodigoEmpacador =Caja.CodigoEmpacador group by Caja.CodigoEmpacador,caja.NumPresentacion,
Empacador.Nombre,Empacador.ApellidoP,Empacador.ApellidoM,Fecha
go

create proc TablaVista
as
begin
select*from Vista pivot(sum(CajasXPresentacion ) for 
PRESENTACION in ([4],[6],[10],[11],[17]))as Total order by Fecha desc
end
```

execute TablaVista

y este es el resultado que me da, ya lo intente ISNULL pero no sé como usarlo correctamente en el pivot

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En la vista deberías cambiar lo siguiente

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(sum(Cantidad), 0) , '')as CajasXPresentacion
```

Por

```
sum(ISNULL(Cantidad, 0)) as CajasXPresentacion
```

De esta forma Cantidad nunca será `null` y por lo tanto tampoco la suma.

Quedaría así:

```
create view Vista
as
select Caja.CodigoEmpacador as CODIGOEMP,Caja.NumPresentacion as PRESENTACION,Empacador.Nombre as NOMBRE,
Empacador.ApellidoP as APELLIDO_PATERNO,Empacador.ApellidoM as APELLIDO_MATERNO,
 Fecha as FECHA, sum(ISNULL(Cantidad, 0)) as CajasXPresentacion
 from Empacador 
inner join (Caja inner join Presentacion on Caja.NumPresentacion =Presentacion.NumPresentacion) on Empacador.CodigoEmpacador =Caja.CodigoEmpacador 
group by Caja.CodigoEmpacador,caja.NumPresentacion,
Empacador.Nombre,Empacador.ApellidoP,Empacador.ApellidoM,Fecha
go

create proc TablaVista
as
begin
   select * from Vista pivot(sum(CajasXPresentacion ) for 
   PRESENTACION in ([4],[6],[10],[11],[17]))as Total 
   order by Fecha desc
end
```

Puedes probarlo así:

```
create table #Temp (Fecha smalldatetime, Num1 int)

insert into #Temp (Fecha, Num1) values ('20180101', 1), ('20180505', NULL), ('20190403', 6)

select Fecha, sum(Num1)
from #Temp
group by Fecha

select Fecha, sum(ISNULL(Num1, 0)) 
from #Temp
group by Fecha
```

Comment: Me sigue saliendo como resultado null y ya hice el cambio que me sugeriste

Comment: He editado la respuesta para poner la vista y procedimientos completos, la vista si la ejecutas debe devolver el campo `CajasXPresentacion` con valor 0 en vez de `null`, que es el valor que recoge el procedimiento

Comment: No, sigue sin funcionarme, no habrá otra forma de sustituir los null por ceros, pero en vez de  la vista, se haga en el pivot, porque los null son de la sumatoria de CajasXPresentacion y no por Cantidad ya que éste es solo una unidad y pertenece solo a uno de las 5 presentaciones 4,6,10,11 y17,

Comment: Si haces `select * from Vista` ¿te aparecen `null` en el campo CajasXPresentacion?

Comment: No, no me aparecen porque, pero cuando hago el pivot si

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el alias del pivot, y aplícale la función isNull

```
SELECT Total.CODIGOEMP
 , Total.NOMBRE
 , Total.APELLIDO_PATERNO
 , Total.APELLIDO_MATERNO
 , Total.FECHA
 , Isnull(Total.[4],0) as [4]
 , Isnull(Total.[6],0) as [6]
 , Isnull(Total.[10],0) as [10]
 , Isnull(Total.[11],0) as [11]
 , Isnull(Total.[17],0) as [17]
FROM Vista PIVOT(SUM(CajasXPresentacion) FOR PRESENTACION IN([4]
                                                       , [6]
                                                       , [10]
                                                       , [11]
                                                       , [17])) AS Total
   ORDER BY Fecha DESC;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no encontraba la forma, tuve que validarlo desde visual 2010 en el datagridview pero ya con ésto lo valido desde SQL Server, muchas gracias